# Office VSTO | Converting a Word Document to Pdf hangs (no progress) when the Word Document has macros in it

Tags: c#, vsto

Using the Office Interops (specifically VSTO) and converting a Word Document (docx) to pdf works perfectly fine.
However, if the Document contains a macro in it, then the conversion hangs.
When trying to convert the same Document directly from within Word (with the GUI), Office TrustCenter asks in a popup dialog if this Document should be trusted or not. However, when using the Office Interops, there is no graphical user interface and thus this popup is never shown and this appears to cause the "hang".

The official Microsoft Documentation mentions that there are two properties that can assist with displaying those dialogs:

- DisplayAlerts
- AutomationSecurity

I've tried setting these, but this does not resolve the issue. When using the code below, the dialogs do not get shown unless the User performs a left-click with their mouse somewhere. The dialogs are not hidden behind anything as they are not shown when using alt-tab.

```
    private void WordConvertToPDF(string pathToFileToConvert, string exportPath)
    {
        Word.Application wordApp = null;
        Word.Documents documents = null;
        Word.Document document = null;

        try
        {
            wordApp = new Word.Application();
            wordApp.DisplayAlerts = Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsAll;
            wordApp.AutomationSecurity = Office.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityByUI;

            documents = wordApp.Documents;

            document = documents.Open(pathToFileToConvert);
            document.ExportAsFixedFormat(
                exportPath,
                Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF,
                Item: Word.WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentWithMarkup
                );
        }
        finally
        {
            if (wordApp != null)
            {
                //Close Word 
                wordApp.Quit(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
            }

            document.ReleaseCOM();
            documents.ReleaseCOM();
            wordApp.ReleaseCOM();
        }
    }
```

To provide further clarification, this code is being called from within Outlook. The User can right-click an attachment in Outlook and then click the button to convert the attachment to Word.

Comment: I would guess you need to set AutomationSecurity like this:
`wordApp.AutomationSecurity = Office.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;`  Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I tried this. This is also (according to MS documentation) the default value. But this did not resolve the issue. The value I am using now "works" when a user performs a left-click with their mouse during the conversion as then the dialog is being shown. But this is of course not acceptable, the dialog should always be shown (or handled).